# Reference .pfx file from within my WebSite application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm developing a WebSite which consumes a web service but I'm having trouble referencing the client certificate file in my code.

I've added the .pfx file to the solution as shown below.

[image: pfx]

This is how I try to build the link to the file, and add the client certificate to my service:

```
var certName = "665300-ws-hg-test.pfx";
var newCertPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"WebSite2\", certName);

DocArchiveV201101 service = new DocArchiveV201101();
service.ClientCertificates.Add(
    new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate(
        newCertPath, certPass));
```

When printing `newCertPath`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\WebSite2\665300-ws-hg-test.pfx
```

The last line of code throws the following error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024893
  Message=the system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       vid System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
       vid System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
       vid System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
       vid System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password)
       vid ASP._Page_index_cshtml.Execute() i c:\Users\marcus.jacobsson\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\index.cshtml:rad 47
       vid System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       vid System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
       vid System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       vid System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       vid System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  InnerException:
```

So my question is; How do I build a proper link to reference the `665300-ws-hg-test.pfx` file in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Furthermore, if the certificate is located in the website root, there is no need to prefix the certificate name with the project folder name:

```
var newCertPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\" + certName);
```